# Cpp code using for loop to increment number from 0 to 9 (user defined)

Tags: c++

what is the problem while defining it by users it is not working so any of you have a solution for this issue...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    cout<<"Enter the value of x =";
    cin>>x;
    for(int x; x < 10; x++)
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your for loop introduces a new (uninitialized) x variable, you have undefined behavior. it should be `for (; x < 10; x++)`

Comment: `for(int x; x < 10; x++)` defines a new `int x` without initializing it, which shadows your `int x;` in the `main` scope.

Comment: Maybe you want `for(int i=0; i < x; i++) {  cout << i << endl;  }` I am not sure because I am unsure of the exact problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Increase your warning level, and compiler would warn for shadowing and more important, uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a variable named `x` twice: First in line 5 and again in line 8 in the `for` loop. The second declaration shadows the first one, i.e. the value entered by the user is never used in the loop. It's better to use a loop variable (like `i`) that is initialized to the value of `x` and incremented after each iteration, i.e.

```cpp
...
cin >> x;
for (int i = x; i < 10; ++i)
{
...
}
```